# State coming back undefined from useEffect

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am trying to setState from useEffect but it comes back as undefined and I am unable to use it in other components. I am able to console log the state though and it displays the object fine. Thanks.

```
function App() {
  const [tokens, setTokens] = useState();

console.log(tokens)

  useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      await Moralis.initPlugins();
      await Moralis.enable();
      await listAvailableTokens();
    }

    init();

    // token info from 1inch
    const listAvailableTokens = async () => {
      const result = await Moralis.Plugins.oneInch.getSupportedTokens({
        chain: "eth", // The blockchain you want to use (eth/bsc/polygon)
      });
      const tokensObject = result.tokens;
      console.log(tokensObject)
      setTokens(tokensObject);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Are you trying to use it as global state? If that's the case, you should probably look at React's context api or Redux.

Comment: It will be `undefined` on initial render because the request has not happened yet. When does it "come back as undefined"?

Comment: If I pass 'tokens' into another component I am unable to access it. For example in a map function. tokens.map((val) => {})